# Convert day + time string to time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to convert a column containing day hour minute and second to time (01 03:08:09) in SQL Server 2014 because it is in the `nvarchar(255)` data type, so that I can use the `DATEDIFF` function and I get an error message:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I tried using;

```
SELECT CAST (Driver_at_restaurant_datetime AS time)
FROM deliveries
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Does the value of that column all in the same format ? Please provide more samples

Comment: yes, This is what a few row looks like Driver_at_restaurant_datetime
01 03:08:09
13 18:24:39
17 19:19:59
12 04:13:02
08 23:54:29
12 04:10:26
12 04:25:32
12 04:26:51

05 02:11:55
02 20:33:15

13 19:24:13

05 21:17:03
12 18:40:28
13 02:44:18
06 02:38:02

Comment: What is the expected output for `01 03:08:09` ? How do you expect `1 Day 3 Hours 8 Minutes 9 Seconds` represented as `time` ?

Comment: _it is in the nvarchar(255) data type_ This is your problem - fix your schema. And stop using misleading names; it is not a date at all. Why bother storing the day?

Answer (score 2):

`01 03:08:09` is not a valid time, so it will produce an error. You need to extract `03:08:09` first with `right()` then convert it to a time as follows:

```
SELECT CAST (right(Driver_at_restaurant_datetime,8) AS time(0))
FROM deliveries
```

Comment: 01:46:58.0000000 This is the output, it returned an incorrect output

Comment: use `SELECT CAST (right(Driver_at_restaurant_datetime,8) AS TIME(0))` @OLUFUNKE

Comment: @OLUFUNKE I have revised my answer which lemon has already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,'1900-01-' + CONVERT(CHAR(2),CAST (LEFT(Driver_at_restaurant,2) AS INT) + 1) + RIGHT(Driver_at_restaurant,9),120)
```

This will convert your string to datetime and will let you apply datediff without loosing the "days" part.

The above implements ODBC cannonical style for convertion. More here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

**EDIT**

Here's a more comprehensive example:

```
declare @testString1 nvarchar(30) = '00 17:47:12';
declare @testString2 nvarchar(30) = '01 03:08:09';

declare @testDate1 Datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME,'1900-01-' + CONVERT(CHAR(2),CAST (LEFT(@testString1,2) AS INT) + 1) + RIGHT(@testString1,9),120)
declare @testDate2 Datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME,'1900-01-' + CONVERT(CHAR(2),CAST (LEFT(@testString2,2) AS INT) + 1) + RIGHT(@testString2,9),120)

SELECT 
    @testDate1 AS TestDate1,
    @testDate2 AS TestDate1,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@testDate1,@testDate2) AS DateDiff_Minutes, 
    DATEDIFF(HOUR,@testDate1,@testDate2) AS DateDiff_Hours, 
    DATEDIFF(DAY,@testDate1,@testDate2) AS DateDiff_Days
```

Comment: It returned this error message "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: @OLUFUNKE did you try debugging it? The approach is correct, it just might need a tweak. Or you might have an invalid value in your table. Inspect the string without the convert and see what you get. Don't just wait for someone to solve it for you - see what you can accomplish yourself.